# What is the difference between these two AuthenticationMethods?

Tags: pam, authentication

What is the difference between the following:

- `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`
- `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam`

The [man page of sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE) says

> For keyboard interactive authentication it is also    possible to
> restrict authentication to a specific device by appending a colon
> followed by the device identifier bsdauth or pam.  depending on
> the server configuration.  For example,
> "keyboard-interactive:bsdauth" would restrict keyboard interac-
> tive authentication to the bsdauth device.

If I know I want to enable PAM for password/2FA authentication, is there any reason I should not use the `:pam` option?

Comment: Please explain *where* those statements are to be found; the "man page" of *what*?

Comment: Updated with the man page and a link